# What is the difference between the two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, where-clause, having

The goal is to display the youngest student in a particular class. I've created the one with the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, but the suggested answer is not using them. While it does make sense how their answer works, I still don't understand why mine doesn't. Shouldn't it be the same?

Mine prints multiple rows of what is probably all the students in the ENROLMENT table. It should do this only if I had omitted the HAVING clause, because of the GROUP BY. But why is it still doing it, even with the HAVING clause telling it to eliminating groups that don't meet the condition?

```
select
  studfname
  || ' '
  || studlname as fullname,
  studdob
from
  uni.student s,
  uni.enrolment e
where
  s.studid = e.studid
  and
  e.unitcode = 'FIT1004'
  and
  studdob =
  (
    select
      min(studdob)
    from
      uni.student s,
      uni.enrolment e
    where
      s.studid = e.studid
      and
      e.unitcode = 'FIT1004'
  )
order by
  s.studid;

SELECT studfname|| ' ' ||studlname AS stud_name, studdob
  FROM uni.student s, uni.enrolment e
  WHERE e.studid = s.studid
    AND unitcode = 'FIT1004'
  GROUP BY studfname, studlname, studdob
  HAVING studdob = min(studdob);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for each member of your group (studfname, studlname, studdob) to be limited to their minimum studdob (that's whart your HAVING clause is doing). Since each member of your group has only one studdob, that studdob is the same as the min(studdob) for that member of the group.

If you change your HAVING clause to use the subquery from the correct answer it will work as expected:

```
HAVING studdob = ( 
    select
      min(birthdate)
    from
      pat_Patient s,
      phy_Physician e
    where
      s.PCPPhysicianSID = e.PhysicianSID
      and
      e.PhysicianSID = 26665
  )
```

This may not be the most elegant approach as other solutions, but to answer your question, this is the reason your query isn't working while the correct one is.

Comment: Ah yes. I see it now. I thought the having clause could compare groups with each other. Is there no other way to compare groups with each other? Other than sub-queries.

Comment: If you want to compare groups to each other, I'd suggest using a temp table or common table expression to first establish your groups, then query against that with a second query to do your comparing/filtering. IMO, temp tables or CTEs are usually easier to read, code, & manipulate than correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` combines all results with the same column value into a single row ( mostly used when you need sums, averages, etc.). While `HAVING` is a sort of `WHERE` that you can use after loading all the results of your query (a post-retrieval condition)

Neither of these will get you the youngest student by themselves. I'm not sure what your column names are, but here is a query I would use:

```
SELECT studentname, studentage, class
FROM students S
WHERE studentage = (select MIN(studentage) from students where class = s.class)
```

it selects all students that have the youngests age of their class